# How can I modify my diagramm or add elements triggered by a pick_event in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, events, event-handling

I am trying to use matplotlib to plot some data and then use a pick_event to pick a data point. This already works with the code below. Now I want to add for example an axvline at the position of the picked data point. Is that possible?

The code below works as I expect but the line "ax.axvline(xdata[idx[0]]" seems to be ignored. Maybe the plot needs to be refreshed or something?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('My first picker')
ax.plot([10, 20, 30],[100, 400, 900], 'o', picker=5)

def onpick(event):
    thismarker = event.artist
    xdata = thismarker.get_xdata()
    idx = event.ind
    ax.axvline(xdata[idx[0]])
    print(xdata[idx[0]])
    print('You picked point: ' + str(idx[0]))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Expected result: A vertical line at the data point that is clicked on appears.
Actual result: The picking event works since it prints X-position and the number of the selected data point, but no vertical line appears.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's ignored, but rather you just forgot to redraw the figure after making any changes. Adding `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` in the `onpick` function should be enough.

Comment: That works! Thank you!